# Why I can't change IIS Express default website

Tags: iis

I modified my `applicationhost.config` like this:

```
<site name="WebSite1" id="1" >
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            <site name="WebSite2" id="2"  serverAutoStart="true">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\test" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8081:localhost" />
                </bindings>
 </site>
```

I've set the second site to auto start (serverAutoStart="true") , but when I launch iisexpress.exe, WebSite1(port 8080) was registered instead of WebSite2(port 8081). Why does this happen?

BTW, if I directly delete Website1, then the iisexpress will auto start WebSite2

(my iis express version is 8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IISExpress doesn't use the `serverAutoStart` attribute, and by default starts the first site defined in your `applicationhost.config` file.  To start WebSite2 by default you can move it before WebSite1 in the file (the `id` doesn't matter), or you can specifically start WebSite2 with:

```
iisexpress /site:WebSite2
```